# Свой значок метки при поиске в Yandex map

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Как можно поменять стандартный значок метки который проставляется при поиске http://joxi.ru/GrqplbwHGKje3A

Используется поиск по организациям  yandex#search . Думал в событии  resultselect фигачить по результату свою метку, но noPlacemark не работает для организаций. Что можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Можно поставить свой значок только на той карте, котрая показана на Вашем собственном сайте.

То есть, если Вы пользуетесь yandex maps, встроив её в сайт, и там показан адрес,к примеру, офиса, то значок, которым показан офис, можно поменять.

Описано добавление своей иконки здесь: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/?turbo=true

Answer (score 0):

```js
function init() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.74, 37.58],
    zoom: 13,
    controls: []
  });

  // Создадим экземпляр элемента управления «поиск по карте»
  // с установленной опцией провайдера данных для поиска по организациям.
  var searchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
    options: {
      provider: 'yandex#search',
      //Изменение цвета меток результатов
      //geoObjectStandardPreset: 'islands#redCircleDotIcon'
    }
  });

  searchControl.events.add('load', function(event) {
    // Проверяем, что это событие не "дозагрузки" результатов и
    // по запросу найден хотя бы один результат.
    if (!event.get('skip') && searchControl.getResultsCount()) {
      var geoObjectsArray = searchControl.getResultsArray();
      geoObjectsArray.forEach(
        marker =>
        marker.options.set({
          iconLayout: 'default#image',
          // Своё изображение иконки метки.
          iconImageHref: 'https://sandbox.api.maps.yandex.net/examples/ru/2.1/icon_customImage/images/myIcon.gif',
          // Размеры метки.
          iconImageSize: [30, 42],
          // Смещение левого верхнего угла иконки относительно
          // её "ножки" (точки привязки).
          iconImageOffset: [-5, -38]
        })
      );
    }
  });

  myMap.controls.add(searchControl);

  // Программно выполним поиск определённых кафе в текущей
  // прямоугольной области карты.
  searchControl.search('Шоколадница');
}

ymaps.ready(init);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.circle_layout {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -23px;
  top: -23px;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  border: 2px solid #225D9C;
  color: #225D9C;
  line-height: 46px;
  /* Это CSS свойство не будет работать в Internet Explorer 8 */
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&apikey=7b1b79b3-8fad-410d-9704-a6f542e7a6bd"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Вы можете переопределить стандартные значки меток, указав параметр geoObjectStandardPreset для ymaps.control.SearchControl
Например, так:

```
var searchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
    options: {
        provider: 'yandex#search',
        //Изменение цвета меток результатов
        geoObjectStandardPreset: 'islands#redCircleDotIcon'
    }
});
```

Если вы хотите сделать именно кастомные иконки, можно переопределить их у результатов поиска.

```
searchControl.events.add('load', function (event) {
// Проверяем, что это событие не "дозагрузки" результатов и
// по запросу найден хотя бы один результат.
if (!event.get('skip') && searchControl.getResultsCount()) {
    var geoObjectsArray = searchControl.getResultsArray();                           
    geoObjectsArray.forEach(
        marker => 
        marker.options.set({
            iconLayout: 'default#image',
            // Своё изображение иконки метки.
            iconImageHref: 'https://sandbox.api.maps.yandex.net/examples/ru/2.1/icon_customImage/images/myIcon.gif',
            // Размеры метки.
            iconImageSize: [30, 42],
            // Смещение левого верхнего угла иконки относительно
            // её "ножки" (точки привязки).
            iconImageOffset: [-5, -38]
        })
    );       
}
});
```